# What's the word for lying in court?

Tags: word-request, legalese

I am not sure what the word is, because I forgot it, but I think for this question there might be several answers, and it depends on the context, there's the word that defines the crime of lying in court (like defamation), and I think there's the act of it, which may not be a crime depending on the context, but I might be wrong. Anyway, just help me remember the word, or just answer the question broadly without considering what I wrote above.

Answer (score 3):

The act of intentionally giving false information under oath is called [**perjury**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perjury). Merriam Webster:

> the voluntary violation of an oath or vow either by swearing to what is untrue or by omission to do what has been promised under oath : false swearing

And the verb form is **perjure**. Oxford Dictionaries:

> willfully tell an untruth when giving evidence to a court; commit perjury.

Someone who commits perjury is called a **perjurer**.